# How to Populate a Object Values to Array of Objects Using the Key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change my array of object values with my object values through the key

```
let a = [
  {
    title: "rewardValue",
    value: "1",
  },
  {
    title: "rewardValue2",
    value: "10",
  },
  {
    title: "rewardValue2",
    value: "12",
  },
];

let aofValue = {
  rewardValue: "200",
  rewardValue2: "500",
  rewardValue3: "800"
};


a.map((val,index) => {


    if(val.title === Object.keys(aofValue)[0]) {

        val.value = aofValue.rewardValue

    }
    if (val.title === Object.keys(aofValue)[1]) {
      val.value = aofValue.rewardValue2;
    }

    if (val.title === Object.keys(aofValue)[2]) {
      val.value = aofValue.rewardValue3;
    }

})

console.log(a);
```

I got what I expected but is there any shorted way to do this ´?
I think the way which I done is completely wrong but it return what I expected any other possible solution for this and if available kindly explain the solution

Comment: u can do `val.value = aofValue[val.title]` dynamically

Comment: Please don't Write with Random upper Case characters Like This. It's very Annoying to read Text like That.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), replacing the value with the property value for the title in the object (accessed with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)).

```js
let a=[{title:"rewardValue",value:"1"},{title:"rewardValue2",value:"10"},{title:"rewardValue2",value:"12"},],
    aofValue={rewardValue:"200",rewardValue2:"500",rewardValue3:"800"};
let res = a.map(o => ({...o, value: aofValue[o.title]}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yeah I Finally figure it out the solution before came to stackoverflow the solution is correct and i added additional condition were the title is available then only  i am assigning to the value

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```js
let a = [ { title: "rewardValue", value: "1", }, { title: "rewardValue2", value: "10", }, { title: "rewardValue2", value: "12", }, ];
let aofValue = { rewardValue: "200", rewardValue2: "500", rewardValue3: "800" };

const output = a.map((item) => {
    return {
        ...item,
        value: aofValue[item.title],
    };
})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
const aofKeys = Object.keys(aofValue);
let aofKey;

for (let row of a) {
  if ((aofKey = aofKeys.indexOf (row.title)) !== -1 )  {
    row.value = aofValue[aofKeys[aofKey]];
  }
}
```

This solution takes into account the fact that *title* of array `a` may not be present in `aofValue`